# How to implement Nlog in xamarin.ios ? & error message should store into Sqlite

Tags: xamarin, nlog

In Our Ios project ,we are planing to implement error log using  NLog and same error message need to store into SQLlite database

Can you please provide me Sample Solutions .

For C# i refereed some code sniper from c# cornar
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/vendettamit/nlog-new-utility-for-smart-logging/

Answer (score 0):

I got nlog sample application

https://github.com/LeslieF-iQMetrix/NLog.IqMetrix